# NullPointerException - Handler.removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, handler, runnable

I got some crash reports from my app on console. I tried to fix it but I stucked. I'm using custom progress dialog, my problem is about that. What should I do? Should I use removeCallBack?

[image: logcat]

```
FlipProgressDialog fpd; // this is my custom progress dialog

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    fpd.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_feeds, container, false);
    this.mView = view;
    fpd = new FlipProgressDialog();  //and initialized here for escape the nullpointer exception but not worked


    fpd.setImageList(imageList); 
    fpd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    // Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Listeleme().execute();
        }
    };

    myRunnable.run();
    //handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
    //I guess I need call the above but I couldn't apply properly
    return view;
}

private class Listeleme extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    String URL="...";

    @Override
    protected  void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        fpd.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"");
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

      //...
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void avoid)
    {
        if (getActivity()!= null) {        
        }
        if (fpd.isVisible()) {
            fpd.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the line 245 - FlipProgressDialog. java

```
    @Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null && getRetainInstance()) {
        dialog.setDismissMessage(null);
    }
    handler.removeCallbacks(r);  // line 245
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, some resources of your FlipProgressDialog are destroyed when you enter onPause(), so calling anything after everything gets destroyed causes that exception. Just try to call `fpd.dismissAllowingStateLoss()` before `super.onPause()`

Comment: When does the exception occurs? As soon as you enter in that activity? At pause?

Comment: it gives error when I force too much, like fast navigation items transitions.

Comment: Maybe it's easy to get error for some users. I'm getting 2-3 these reports daily on play console